# Honda ATV TRX350 4x4 '89engine remove, how to disconnect from drive shafts?

Tags: honda, atv

I bought an 1989 Honda TR350 4x4 with possibly a blown rod bearing/scratched piston.

The quad itself
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hyRa.jpg

I'm trying to remove the engine, I have almost everything disconnected but the mounts and the output shafts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvNVZ.jpg

Here you can see the forward drive shaft attach point

i.imgur.com/8zFXc2p.jpg (sorry, can't paste more than 2 links)

Here you can see the rearward drive shaft attach point

i.imgur.com/5vx64YU.jpg

How do I disconnect these ?

I watched this video

www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_WQSVeO7bI

and I least I know NOT to unbolt the output angle drive/transfert case as this will collapse the gears in the transmission.

Any advice welcomed

Comment: Can't help with your question, but nice shop!

Comment: Do you have a service manual on your quad?

Comment: Thanks !   Yes I have found the manual. 

http://www.mtaonline.net/~adambultman/1986-1989%20Fourtrax-Foreman%20350.pdf     

Under the center shaft guard. There was a retaining ring inside of a cup holding the center shaft as one piece, the manual says to undo the carrier bearing and use a drift to knock the center shaft toward the front.

I will try this on the weekend !